# Selecting DataRows into new structures using LINQ. Calling Distinct() fails

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Consider these two structures:

```
struct Task
{
    public Int32 Id;
    public String Name;
    public List<Registration> Registrations;
}

struct Registration
{
    public Int32 Id;
    public Int32 TaskId;
    public String Comment;
    public Double Hours;
}
```

I am selecting a bunch of entries in a DataTable into new structures, like so:

```
var tasks = data.AsEnumerable().Select(t => new Task
{
    Id = Convert.ToInt32(t["ProjectTaskId"]),
    Name = Convert.ToString(t["ProjectTaskName"]),
    Registrations = new List<Registration>()
});
```

But when I call `Distinct()` on the collection, it doesn't recognize objects with the same values (*Id*, *Name*, *Registrations*) as being equal.

But if I use an equality comparer; comparing the *Id* property on the objects, it's all fine and dandy...:

```
class TaskIdComparer : IEqualityComparer<Task>
{
    public bool Equals(Task x, Task y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }


    public Int32 GetHashCode(Task t)
    {
        return t.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Is `Distinct()` checking something else than the value of properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ's `Distinct` method compares objects using the objects' `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations.
Therefore, if these methods are not overridden, it will compare by reference, not by value.

You need to use an `EqualityComparer`.  (Or implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for the `Task` class)

Comment: ...which, undoubtedly, fails for the list of registrations.

Comment: And the reference, in this case, would be what?

Comment: @roosteronacid: By default, it will only consider two references equal if they refer to the same instance.

Comment: Thanks SLaks. That really boggled my head :)

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that it's the list in there. Almost certainly, the two list objects are different, even if they contain the same info.